# Cortana activation issues

Tags: windows, cortana

I've upgraded 3 computers to Win 10 successfully. One is a laptop and the other two desktops. Activating Cortana on the laptop worked fine. I moved on to one of the desktops and now I am having a problem. I am using my Hotmail/Outlook account as my Microsoft account to activate Cortana. On the desktop, I enter the user name and password, as I did on the laptop, click next and the next page wants me to enter my "old" password one more time. I re-enter the same password, since I assume that is what it is calling for, and click next. The next window tells me that my password is incorrect, but it is correct. I didn't have this issue with the laptop activation. Does anyone know why this might be happening? I need to solve this then activate Cortana on the second desktop PC. I'm frankly surprised that I have to enter all of this info on each computer. Maybe there is a way to sync Cortana, but I don't know if that is possible.

I also had the problem of no sound when I did the upgrade on one desktop PC, but I went online and downloaded the correct Win 10 driver and it works again. These have, so far been my only two issues.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes a week late but hopefully it might help someone who comes across the same issue.

When Cortana asks you to enter your old password one last time, enter the password of the account you are logged on to the computer. For example if you log on to the computer with username john and password 0x00FF00-is-Blue, type in that password.